# Calculate IQR for selected observations

Tags: r, if-statement, iqr

I have the following data and I would like to calculate IQR for only for those whose sex is equal to 1.

[image]

I have tried

```r
if(Agogo$sex_2015==2) { IQR(Agogo$bmi) }
```

Is there any way to do this using ifelse or any other condition?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried?

Comment: if(Agogo$sex_2015==2)
{
  IQR(Agogo$bmi)
}

Comment: IQR of what? bmi?

Comment: library(tidyverse)

df %>% filter(sex == 1) %>% summarise(quantile(bmi,.25))

Comment: `IQR(df$bmi[df$sex_2015==1])`

Comment: @Dasr is there any benefit to use `tidyverse` to calculate IQR just for `bmi`? (Unless the OP want to get IQRs for multiple columns at the same time, `summarise(across(...))` is a nice choice) Btw, what you suggest is just the first quartile, not IQR...

Comment: Fair enough.....it wasn't an answer, just suggestion. Can easily be modified with additional arguments. Also, my preference is tidyverse for this type of thing, there are thousands of ways to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the get IQR of bmi

```
library(dplyr)
bmi<- sample(100,10)
edu_mo<-sample(50,10)
sex<-sample(2,10,replace= TRUE)

n<-data.frame(bmi,edu_mo,sex)

n %>% 
  filter(sex == 1) %>% 
  summarize(IQR = IQR(bmi))
```